# Print not cleared alarms from bash or awk

Tags: bash, awk

I need to find the alarm records from a file which are not yet cleared. To achive that, I need to check from the alarm-id(4th column) which are never marked CLEARED.

Logic: Print the alarms which are set and cleared. Each alarm has a unique identifier of alarm-id in 4th column. Sometimes some alarms may get escalate to higher severity before getting cleared. For example in following input alarm with ID 102 was minor initially but it first escalated to critical and the finally get cleared.

Alarms which are not needed:

```
102---set
102---Escalated to critical
102---Cleared
```

OR

```
103---set 
103---cleared
```

Alarms needs in output

```
104---set
104---NEVER CLEARED
```

## sample input:

```
2017-05-23T05:45:41 node-1 MINOR    102 alarm_text1
2017-05-23T05:45:43 node-2 MAJOR    103 alarm_text2
2017-05-23T05:45:41 node-1 CRITICAL 102 alarm_text1   #Escalation
2017-05-23T05:45:47 node-4 CRITICAL 104 alarm_text3
2017-05-23T05:45:51 node-1 CLEARED  102 alarm_text1
2017-05-23T05:45:43 node-2 CLEARED  103 alarm_text2
```

## Desired output:

```
2017-05-23T05:45:47 node-4 CRITICAL 104 alarm_text3
```

I tried this but no help:

```
grep -v 'CLEARED'

awk '!a[$4]++'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk solution:

```
awk -v s="CLEARED" '$3!=s{a[$4]=$0} $3==s{delete a[$4]} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file

2017-05-23T05:45:47 node-4 CRITICAL 104 alarm_text3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with an `Awk` logic like below,

```
awk '{alarm[$4]=(alarm[$4] FS $3); text[$4]=$0; next}END{for (i in alarm) if (!match(alarm[i],/CLEARED/)) print text[i] }' file
```

which will produce an output as

```
2017-05-23T05:45:47 node-4 CRITICAL 104 alarm_text3
```

The idea here is to store all statuses for a particular alarm as a hash-map, keyed by the alarm-id, such that once all the lines are processed, you get an information as

```
102  MINOR CRITICAL CLEARED
103  MAJOR CLEARED
104  CRITICAL
```

The key here is *not* to look for single instance of status, which may give a false information if an alarm transitions from one state to another. So checking if the state, `CLEARED` is not there would be the right way.